# Access ruby array in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I want to access a Ruby array in javascript. Please tell me the method to do that. My array is holding the result of a sql query.

```
  @contacts = Contact.order("contacts.position ASC")
```

I am trying to do this....

```
for(var i=0; i< a; i++)
    {   
        var firstnameV = "<%=Contact.order('contacts.position ASC')[i].first_name%>";
        var lastnameV = "<%=Contact.order('contacts.position ASC')[i].last_name%>";
        var emailV = "<%=Contact.order('contacts.position ASC')[i].email%>";
        var contactV = parseInt("<%=Contact.order('contacts.position ASC')[i].contact_no%>";
        var posV = parseInt("<%=Contact.order('contacts.position ASC')[i].position%>";  
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO contact_table (firstname, lastname, email, contact, pos)
        VALUES (firstnameV,lastnameV, emailV, contactV, posV)');
    }
```

Comment: Just render json and access it through ajax

Comment: @apneadiving  Could you please show the steps. I am totally new at rails and ajax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick example of how you can render the value of Ruby variable to JavaScript. Add <%= yield :head %> to head tag in `views/layouts/application.html.erb`. Then in `views/contacts/index.erb` (or whatever view you use) add the following:

```
<%content_for :head do %>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    alert("First contact in database is <%=Contact.order('contacts.position ASC').first.name%>")
}
</script>
<%end%>
```

This will alert the first contact name from your database.

Comment: @Nikita: How am I suppose to select a particular element for the array. For eg.When I try to do this <%=Contact.order('contacts.position ASC')[i].first.name%> it shows error. A constant in the place of 'i' works fine.  The error is undefined local variable i.

Comment: @dilip - OK, it gets a bit more advanced. <% somecode %> in view executes ruby code. <%= ruby variable %> (note = sign) inserts value of ruby variable to the html code in view. So one option for you can be constructing a loop and then inserting it to your view with <% %>

Comment: @nikita: I know how to add ruby variables to html code. But here i want to assign ruby variable to javascript variable. I tried doing this var first =  "<%=Contact.order('contacts.position ASC')[i].first_name%>"; But it works only if i give a contant number in the place of i. Else it shows local variable undeclared.

Comment: Exactly. `var first = ` is outside <% %> so it will be parsed as a part of html code, not as Ruby code. Use something like `<% i = 5 %><%=Contact.order('contacts.position ASC')[i].first_name%>` or even a loop, depending what you want.

Comment: `<% @contacts = Contact.order("contacts.position ASC") %><%a = 10%><% for i in 0 do %>var firstname = <%=@contacts[i].first_name%><%end%>`

Comment: What you got wrong is that you did not declare variable i anywhere in ruby part of view. In your code i is a Javascript variable, and for loop is a loop in Javascript, since it these are not enclosed in <% %>

Comment: Ah, the loop should be for i in 0..a Sorry for typo

Comment: Thnx Nikita. But now I am facing another problem. I have a view named 'new' in which I will be displaying a form. On its submit action I am running a create method in the controller which adds the object to my server side database. Now since I wanna update both offline and online database simultaneously, Where can I write the javascript we have discussed above.

Comment: @dilip, please do not edit your question into an answer. We're not a forum! This makes this question hard to read for future readers. Also, please do not continue asking new questions once the original has been answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the

> to_json

method in Ruby

or

> render :json => @contacts

Comment: After that how am I suppose to use it in javscript? I am totally new to rails.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is server side language. JavaScript is mostly (server side also - e.g. node.js) client side. If you want to pass values from Ruby to JS, you could render that value as part of view in `script` tags or retrieve them via AJAX.

Comment: @Tarscher gave you an example in his answer :) And I suggest reading about JSON: http://www.json.org/