# Ajax response from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My javascript send Ajax request which will invoke a controller function, then the controller function response to the Ajax request. My problem is in the controller response part.

my javascript which send Ajax request to controller:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
          //RENDER RESPONSE @cars here
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","/cars/reserved_cars/"+customer_id,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

So, the above ajax request will invoke my `CarsController`'s `reserved_cars` function with `customer_id` as parameter.

My CarsController:

```
class CarsController < BaseController

def reserved_cars
    customer_id=params[:customer_id]

    @cars = Car.getCars(customer_id)
  end
...


end
```

My controller get all cars by query Car model with customer_id.

Everything works fine, I just don't know how to return the @cars in controller as response of my ajax request to my javascript (the place in my javascript where I commented "**//RENDER RESPONSE @cars here**")

So, How to get @cars response in my javascript?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks guys, I figured out the solution.

I first convert @cars to string `cars_str`,

then use `render :json => cars_str` in my controller,

in my javascript I can get this `cars_str` string with `xmlhttp.responseText`

Comment: more specific code snippets and in which files they are used would be more helpful :)

Comment: man i love you - `render json: {"name" => username}` worked for me

Answer (score 1):

HTTP protocol always transfers the string, if you are trying to return array or other non scalar variable you will fail.
The solution would be to format your variable as a string and then parse it in JavaScript.

Comment: I can format @cars in a string in my controller, but how can I get the string in my javascript???

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write an ajax [response](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to)

class CarsController < BaseController

```
def reserved_cars
    customer_id=params[:customer_id]

    @cars = Car.getCars(customer_id)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

In your cars view you add reserved_cars.js.rjs that contains the javascript. This file contains your javascript code like:

```
page.replace_html :cars, :partial => '/cars/car', :collection => @cars
```

replace_html will replace the inner html of the DOM element with id `cars` (eg.  `<div id="cars"></div>`) . the partial displays 1 car

I hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, I dont get you. What is this format.js?? if I want to get @cars in my javascript where I commented "//RENDER RESPONSE @cars here", how to do??

Comment: Actually, I dont show cars in my view, I just needs @cars in my javascript. So, My question is on how to get @cars in my javascript file where I commented "//RENDER RESPONSE @cars here"

Comment: You want to have the data only? Then you need to convert the @cars into json. You should read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883918/access-ruby-array-in-javascript/4884054#4884054

Comment: Why exactly do you need the @cars data in javascript? Don't you want to render the cars data at some point?

Comment: Yes, I only want the @cars data in my javascript. The reason why I implement this is purely because my javascript needs some data from database. Then I though I could use ajax to implement this. That's why I dont render the cars on any page.

Answer (score 0):

This page

```
"/cars/reserved_cars/"+customer_id"
```

Needs to return a page with text on it. This text can then be accessed by accessing the `responseText` of your xmlhttp object.

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
          //RENDER RESPONSE @cars here
          responseFromCar = xmlhttp.responseText;
   }
```

Where `responseFromCar` will be the text returned from your request. Then just parse the text as necessary to find the associated info you need.

Note: You could also use `responseXML` instead of `responseText` if you are expecting a properly formatted XML page back from your request. This approach would make parsing it a bit easier.

Comment: Ok, the thing is I don't wanna have any extra page. I would like to use javascript to access server to get data from database, then, my javascript can use the returned data from database. That's why I use Ajax call, do you have any other way to implement if I don't wanna use a page for the server response??

Comment: You code is returning a value, that value has to be returned in some way. You should not look at it so much as it is returning a "page" but rather it is returning a response to your request. The response could be as simple as having a single word returned from a function.